# Azure Application Insights 'No Access' permissions issue

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to setup some Azure application insights web tests on a coworker's azure account.  He gave me Reader & Application Insights Component Contributor, then Owner roles for that resource group.  No luck.  As the owner I then went and gave myself all the other roles, one by one, and logging off and back on each time and it still says 'No Access' and the '+Add Web Test' button is still greyed out.  I also see 'No Access' for alert rules, but I haven't gotten that far yet. This seems like a bug.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

P.S. I did see the same problem discussed [here](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-preview-portal/suggestions/7876524-allow-application-insights-to-be-viewed-by-non-azu) but with no resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Since webtests are an Azure resources themselves. So in order to gain access you will need contributor level access at the ResourceGroup under which your AI resource exists.

Hope this helps.

Comment: See more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-resources-roles-access-control